# Laravel HTTP Client does not work with empty body but Postman works

Tags: laravel, postman, guzzle, paypal-rest-sdk

So I'm having an interesting issue with Laravel HTTP Client while trying to hit an API endpoint for PayPal.

I can get Laravel HTTP Client working on all my endpoints that POST with data, but this one endpoint that **only** requires headers (**no data** is passed in the body) fails with an error.

```
{
   "name":"INVALID_REQUEST",
   "message":"Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.",
   "debug_id":"609388c4ddfe4",
   "details":[
      {
         "field":"\/",
         "location":"body",
         "issue":"INVALID_SYNTAX",
         "description":"MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON"
      }
   ],
   "links":[
      {
         "href":"https:\/\/developer.paypal.com\/docs\/api\/orders\/v2\/#error-INVALID_SYNTAX",
         "rel":"information_link",
         "encType":"application\/json"
      }
   ]
}
```

When I hit the same endpoint in Postman **everything works** fine

My method for hitting the endpoint looks like this

```
public static function capture($order)
{
  $token =  Paypal::fetchToken();
  $api_url = config('services.paypal.api_url') . '/v2/checkout/orders/' . $order['id'] . '/capture';
  
  $headers = [
     'Content/Type'  => 'application/json',
  ];

  $response = Http::withToken($token)
  ->withHeaders($headers)
  ->post($api_url)
  ->json();

  return $response;
}
```

- I have tried passing an empty array in the post request like this `->post($api_url, [])` but that did not work either.
- I have hardcoded the $api_url just in case I made a mistake with my formatting with variables. Resulted in the same issue.
- I have tried changing the `'Content/Type'` in the header to `'none'`. This did not work either and also doesn't make sense because I have this same header set in postman and it works fine (PayPal docs also says to pass this content/type)

Based on the error I am receiving I can only assume the request is hitting the endpoint correctly, but either the HTTP wrapper or guzzle itself is adding something to the body when I leave it blank and it is causing PayPal to throw the error. Don't really know what else I can try though.

Is there a parameter I am overlooking for specifying an empty body on a post request?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't tell why or what, but yes -- definitely *something* is being passed in the body when this request makes its way to PayPal

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source I found the following solution

```
$response = Http::withToken($token)
  ->withHeaders($headers)
  ->send("POST", $api_url)
  ->json();
```

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me for a Dropbox API endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but I fixed it with a simple trick. 
I found the solution on https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json.

This code should work.

```
$response = Http::withToken($token)
  ->withHeaders($headers)
  ->post($api_url,['json' => []])
  ->json();
```

The empty array is now seen as an empty array/body in JSON.